# Docker Compose Make Shared Volume Writable Permission Denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this image that writes into the /temp/config and I wanted to map those data into a shared volume in my host

```
docker-compose downversion: '2'

services:
  service-test:
    image: service-test:latest
    container_name: service-test
    volumes:
      - source_data:/temp/config/

volumes:
    source_data:
```

When my service-test:latest image tries to write into the /temp/config, I am getting a Permission Denied error.

Question, how do I make this host shared volume writable?

I checked the shared volume using

```
docker volume inspect source_data
```

and I noticed that it has no write functionality.
This is a linux based distro.

**UPDATE 2:**
To verify this, I tried checking the permissions on the shared volume
and I noticed that it has no write permissions also.

```
bash-4.2$ docker inspect volume service-test_source_data
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/scratch/docker/volumes/service-test_source_data/_data",
        "Name": "configservice-test_config_data",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

bash-4.2$ ls -l /scratch/docker/volumes/service-test_source_data/
**drwxr-xr-x** 1 root root 0 Apr 18 01:43 _data
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe your container is running as some specific user other than root.

In your docker-compose.yml you can add user: root

See [docker-compose-reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)

Comment: The container is running as root.  Please see my Update 2.  I am not sure why the permissions set on a shared volume does not have a write access for.

Comment: Can you show what permissions you are getting inside container at mount point : /temp/config/             and also ``id`` command

``#>docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> sh``

Comment: This is the values when I do in the container `ls -l /temp` drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr 18 08:43 config

Comment: oopp sory mate.. id command.. uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: Login again into the container ``#>docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> sh`` and then ``cd /temp/config/  && touch tempfile.txt``

Comment: Hmmm.. for some reason I was able to add the file and see it in my Host also.. Could this be a problem in my java program that writes into the /temp/config folder?  But I don't see any reason why my java program wont be able to write anything when permissions are set on the folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169314/discussion-between-fly2matrix-and-mark-estrada).

Answer (score -3):

You can try it like:

```
volumes:
      - source_data:/temp/config/ 
...
RUN chown -R source_data
```

Comment: Will there be a problem if I do this?  I was under the impression that shared volumes should be writable.. Could it be possible that the mapped volumes is owned by a different user that runs my image so thats why permission issue is encountered?

Comment: Regarding problems: typically you run your containers under specific user that own shared as well. So, in most cases it's quite safe to write/read there